# Angular - Iterate array backwards and forwards is undefined

Tags: angular

The aim is to have a loop that can go backwards and forwards through the array. The array is working fine . But the problem is while clicking on function forward or backward. I have an error, which says the array is `undefined`!

```
this.imgs = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'];

this.index = this.imgs.length;
this.image$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  startWith(this.imgs[0]),
  takeWhile(() => !this.stoploop),
  map(() => {
    this.isImageLoaded = true
    return this.imgs[this.imgs.length - this.index++ % this.imgs.length - 1]
  })
);

backward() {
  if (this.index === (this.imgs.length - 1)) {
    return;
  }
  console.log( this.imgs[++this.index] );
}

forward() {

  if (this.index === 0) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(this.index[--this.index]);
}
```

[Full code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4nneae)

Comment: Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Your forward goes backwards (`--`) and your backward goes forward (`++`)?

Comment: in your `forward`, you have `this.index[--this.index]`. Possibly should be `this.imgs[--this.index]`?

Comment: Please include all code necessary to reproduce this issue in the question itself, not only on an external site. See [mre] and [ask].